# Is the Mackey topology $\tau(l^{\infty},l^{1})$ strongly Lindelöf?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $l^{\infty}$ (respectively, $l^{1}$) be the space of bounded
(respectively, absolutely summable) real sequences. I need to find out if
$l^{\infty}$ equipped with the Mackey topology $\tau(l^{\infty},l^{1})$, i.e.
the finest locally convex topology that leads to the topological dual $l^{1}$,
is strongly/hereditarily Lindelöf.

It would also help to know if $l^{\infty}$ admits a subspace that is not
paracompact or normal, relative to the Mackey topology.

This is a curious case because $l^{\infty}$ equipped with weak* topology is
strongly Lindelöf (as a countable union of second countable balls), while
it is not Lindelöf with respect to the norm-topology. The Mackey topology
is finer than the former and coarser than the latter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't get anything here I think that this question is suitable for MathOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will indeed try MathOverflow.

Comment: The answer is positive, as you can see here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/286334/117369

Comment: I've seen and upvoted it on MathOverflow.